# Selecting multiple objects of the same type

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I have a `TabControl` with three `TextBoxes` that must all be populated. I'm aware there is a "sort of" method of selecting multiple controls of the same type in an overall form, however I was wondering if there was a simple way to select all the `TextBoxes` *within* the `TabControl`. Something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
void checkAllBoxes(object object)
{
    using ((all of type TextBox) in TabControl)
    {
        if object.Text.HasValue;
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
{
     foreach (TextBox textBox in tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Cast<TextBox>())
     {
          textBox.Text = "";//or something else
     }
}
```

Comment: @Wolfish ... Check my updated answer. it loops through all tabs and find all `TextBoxes`.

Comment: @TimPohlmann I mean without having to use a foreach loop. Or does that sound ridiculous? I'm not sure if I'm asking the impossible/idiotic here.

Comment: It isn't possible really. you DO have to loop through to find the specific type of control. remember, all controls derive from "Control" class as base class... then specific controls are inherited and extended from it. The above code only returns the textboxes that are available on the current tab in the foreach loop

Comment: @Wolfish Well you have a lot of different items. Your processor can only check them one at a time. You have to loop somehow. You could use a Linq Statement that looks a bit less loopy, but it will do similar things under the hood.

Comment: @TimPohlmann So no matter how I formulate my test, it has to loop through every control in the form first to find the objects of that type, then through each corresponding object?

Comment: @Wolfish not quite sure, what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the textboxes inside a tab page like this:

```
var txtList =  tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .Where(c => c is TextBox)
    .ToList();
```